# How to confirm that an upload goes "directly" to S3, without proxying through the backend server first? (Python Flask example)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, fine-uploader

I am curious how to tell the difference between using Fineuploader to upload files to S3 using the traditional method of proxying the files first through the backend versus doing a direct upload from the client.
Here is the backend code I have in place that I retrieved from the Fineuploader Github and tweaked slightly to my usecase.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# app.py
#
# by: Mark Feltner
#
# Server-side S3 upload example for Fine Uploader
#
# Features:
# * Upload to S3
# * Delete from S3
# * Sign Policy documents (simple uploads) and REST requests (chunked/multipart)
#   uploads
# * non-CORS environment

import base64, hmac, hashlib, os, sys
from flask import (Flask, abort, json, jsonify, make_response, render_template, request)
from boto.s3.connection import Key, S3Connection

AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = '********************************'
AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY = '************************'
AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY = '*********************************'
AWS_EXPECTED_BUCKET = 'mybucket'
AWS_MAX_SIZE = 1500000000

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='static', static_url_path='/static')
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.debug = True


def sign_policy(policy):
    """ Sign and return the policy document for a simple upload.
    http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/#signyours3postform """
    signed_policy = base64.b64encode(policy)
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
        app.config.get('AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'), signed_policy, hashlib.sha1).
                                 digest())
    return {'policy': signed_policy, 'signature': signature}


def sign_headers(headers):
    """ Sign and return the headers for a chunked upload. """
    return {
        'signature': base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
            app.config.get('AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'), headers, hashlib.sha1).
                                      digest())
    }


@app.route("/s3/sign", methods=['POST'])
def s3_signature():
    """ Route for signing the policy document or REST headers. """
    request_payload = request.get_json()
    if request_payload.get('headers'):
        response_data = sign_headers(request_payload['headers'])
    else:
        response_data = sign_policy(request.data)
    return jsonify(response_data)


@app.route("/s3handler/<key>", methods=['POST', 'DELETE'])
def s3_delete(key=None):
    """ Route for deleting files off S3. Uses the SDK. """
    try:
        s3 = S3Connection(app.config.get("AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY"),
                          app.config.get("AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY"))
        request_payload = request.values
        bucket_name = request_payload.get('bucket')
        key_name = request_payload.get('key')
        aws_bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)
        aws_key = Key(aws_bucket, key_name)
        aws_key.delete()
        return make_response('', 200)
    except ImportError:
        abort(500)


@app.route("/s3/success", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def s3_success():
    """ Success redirect endpoint for <=IE9. """
    return make_response('', 200)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


def main(argv=None):
    app.run('0.0.0.0')

    return 0  # success


if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = main()
    sys.exit(status)
```

On the client side, minus the UI code, I have this script to handle the requests by the client

```
<script>
    var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
        debug: true,
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
        request: {
            endpoint: 'mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
            accessKey: '***************'
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '/s3/sign'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/s3/success'
        },
        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true // defaults to false
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '/s3handler'
        }
    });
</script>
```

This works for me. The files uploaded appear in my S3 bucket. I am assuming this is uploading to S3 "directly" by merely asking the backend to sign the policy file and then continuing on. Is this correct? What would be done differently to have to file pass through the backend instead of being uploaded directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "tell the difference?" Upload directly to S3: `qq.s3.FineUploader`. Upload to a server of your choice: `qq.FineUploader`.

Comment: That is the difference I was looking for! The two different API methods. Thank you @RayNicholus

Comment: Please do post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some clarification from Ray Nicholus, the difference between uploading upload directly to S3 or an alternative server is in the Fineuploader client side methods

Upload directly to S3: qq.s3.FineUploader

Upload to a server of your choice: qq.FineUploader